# Maximum likelihood estimator of the parameter of randomness in Watts and Strogatz's model (1998)

Tags: r, optimization, inference, likelihood, social-network

According to the paper

Menezes, M. B., Kim, S., & Huang, R. (2017). Constructing a Watts-Strogatz network from a small-world network with symmetric degree distribution. *PloS one*, 12(6), e0179120,

I wrote the R-code I attach to estimate via maximum likelihood the parameter of randomness $p$, based on Watts and Strogatz's model (1998), of a social network represented by its adjacency matrix. For more details about Watts and Strogatz's model, you can read

Watts, D. J., & Strogatz, S. H. (1998). Collective dynamics of ‘small-world’ networks. *Nature*, 393(6684), 440.

```
install.packages("sna")
install.packages("igraph")
library(sna)
library(igraph)

# This is the Log-likelihood function in Meneses et al.'s article (2017).
# This function receives as inputs:
#    p: parameter of randomness, based on Watts and Strogatz's model, and
#    AdjMat: adjacency matrix of the social network.

loglike <- function(p, AdjMat){
    n <- nrow(AdjMat)                 # n: number of nodes
    Dens <- sna::gden(AdjMat)         # Dens: network density of the social network.
    K <- round(Dens * (n - 1)/2, 0)   # K: number of neighbors a node has to its right side in the regular lattice before rewiring.

    # logProbs: vector of the logarithm of the probabilities of observing the degree centrality of each node in social network, based on Menezes et al.'s paper.
    logProbs <- log(apply(X = matrix(seq(n), ncol = 1), 
        MARGIN = 1, 
        FUN = function(j){
            m <- sum(AdjMat[, j])
            LowLim <- max(c(2 * K - m, 0))
            UppLim <- min(c(n - 1 - m, 2 * K))
            a <- 1/2 * p * (n - 1 - 2 * K)/n
            b <- p/n
            Factor1 <- dbinom(x = LowLim:UppLim, size = 2 * K, prob = a)
            Factor2 <- dbinom(x = m - 2 * K + LowLim:UppLim, size = (n - 2) * K, prob = b)
            sum(Factor1 * Factor2)
            }
        ))
    sum(logProbs)      # output: loglikelihood of observed data.
    }
```

Now, I am going to build the sampling distribution of the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of the parameter of randomness $p$ by:

i) setting a value of $p$, e.g. $p = 0.2$,

ii) generating $1000$ social networks according to Watts and Strogatz's model,  conditionally on a network density $d$, e.g. $d = 0.1$, a number $N$ of nodes, e.g. $N = 100$, and $p = 0.2$,

iii) estimating $p$ via maximum likelihood for each network generated, and

iv) obtaining the frequency distribution of these $1000$ maximum likelihood estimations of $p$.

```
p <- 0.2
d <- 0.1   
N <- 100
MLE_p <- NULL
for(i in 1:1000){
    K <- round(d * (N - 1)/2, 0)
    AdjMat <- as.matrix(igraph::get.adjacency(igraph::watts.strogatz.game(dim = 1, 
    size = N, nei = K, p = p)))
    OptProblem <- nlminb(start = runif(1),
        objective = function(x) -loglike(p = x, AdjMat = AdjMat),
        lower = 0, upper = 1,
        control = list(trace = TRUE))
    MLE_p <- c(MLE_p, OptProblem$par)
    }

hist(MLE_p, col = "gray60")
```

Following the histogram, the sampling distribution of the MLE of $p$ is not centered on $p$. According to statistical inference, this should not occur.

I was wondering if you could tell me what my mistake is and how I can ammend it, please. If you have questions, please let me know.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.